# Short proof or wrong proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

I found in Borceux' Categorical Algebra the following proposition:

in an abelian category, the following are equivalent:

1) $f:A\longrightarrow B$ is a mono

2) $\operatorname{Ker} f=0$

3) for every $g, f\circ g=0\Rightarrow g=0$

The proof takes several pages and is very complicated, even if not so difficult. I have a very brief proof, and  am wondering if it is shorter and correct or simply shorter (but wrong) than Bourceux one. Here is my proof:

1)$\Rightarrow$ 2) Clearly $f\circ 0=0$. If $fg=0$ for some $g$, then $fg=0=f0$, hence $g=0$ since $f$ is mono, hence $g$ factors uniquely through $0$, thus $0$ is a kernel

2)$\Rightarrow$ 3) Let $g$ be such that $fg=0$. Then $g$ factors through $\operatorname{Ker}f=0$, so $g$ is a zero morphism

3)$\Rightarrow$ 1) Assume $f\alpha=f\beta$, for some $\alpha, \beta:C\rightrightarrows A$. Then
$$f\alpha-f\beta=0$$
$$f(\alpha -\beta)=0$$
$$\alpha -\beta=0$$
$$\alpha=\beta$$

Comment: -1: you did not say which proposition (it's 1.5.4 in Volume II); the additive structure of abelian categories which you use is only introduced in the following section 1.6 and is not part of Borceux's definition of abelian category (zero object, products, coproducts, kernels, cokernels, every monomorphism a kernel, every epimorphism a cokernel). Also his proof + what it cites is shorter than your proof + the proof that abelian categories are additive.

Comment: I think your proof is just fine.

Comment: @Vladimir Sotirov "his proof + what it cites is shorter than your proof + the proof that abelian categories are additive" — even worse, Borceux uses that proposition in his proof of additivity of abelian categories :-)

Comment: @bateman If you assume that an abelian category is additive, then your proof is fine. (I think for all the usual abelian categories the additive structure is known from the very beginning; it is just useful to understand that that structure is actually rigid, it arises from the category, it is not some extra piece of data that you can alter.)